# CURL is enabled in PHP but disabled in Laravel

Tags: php, curl, laravel-5.3

I want to use CURL in my Laravel 5.3 app but it returns error :

```
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\curl_init()
```

I created info.php file to test curl contains :

```
<?php 
    var_dump(function_exists('curl_version'));
    phpinfo();
?>
```

it returns true and shows that curl is enabled :

[image]

but when I test it **inside laravel** :

```
dd(function_exists('curl_version'));
```

it returns **false** !!

When I run `php --ini`  in terminal it returns :

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_curl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_curl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I tried to use curl_init() in info.php outside laravel and it works!

Why does this happen and how to fix it ?

Comment: try `\curl_init()`

Comment: when I use curl_init() the error is :
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\curl_init()
when I use \curl_init() the error becomes :
Call to undefined function curl_init()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running Laravel with:

```
php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

but when I changed it to :

```
php artisan serve --host my_private_IP
```

it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

In your error message PHP tries to resolve the `curl_init` function within the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace. If the underlying issue is not related to the PHP Warning you later pasted, the curl functions should work if you prefix them with backslash, like `\curl_init`.

This way you're telling PHP that the function resides within the top level namespace, not within `App\Http\Controllers`

Comment: when I use curl_init() the error is : Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\curl_init() when I use \curl_init() the error becomes : Call to undefined function curl_init()

Comment: I tried to use curl_init() in info.php outside laravel and it works!
so, why it's not working with laravel ??!

Comment: How are you running Laravel?

Comment: I was running it : php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 but when I remove the host option it work . Thanks @mhitza

Comment: but I want to use --host=0.0.0.0 to make my API accessible from other devices in my network, what should I do and what is the problem with curl and this host ??

Comment: I'm as puzzled as you as of why without the host parameter curl suddenly works. The only reason I have asked how you run Laravel was expecting a simpler issue, like Laravel using the standard version of php.ini, while your tests are using the cli version of php.ini (or the other way around). Needs more debugging from your part if you want to have a clear view why this issue happens :)